# NoActionBar On Marshmallow

Tags: android

I want to hide actionBar But it Just a little faded :

Style :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/background</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/background</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Manifest :

```
<application
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Result :

[image]

Just a little faded, I'm only having problems with marshmallow devices (6.0.1)

Comment: Clear your question. What do you want actually?

Comment: i want to hide actionBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still using AppTheme which has Actionbar

**Add this style to your style file**

```
 <style name = "NoActionBar" parent = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name = "android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name = "android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

**and you need to change**
`android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

**in manifest to**
 `android:theme = "@style/NoActionBar"`

```
<application
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

there is another ways to hide action bar like:

**1.**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" 
          android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**2. using hide method**

```
 // Hide ActionBar

if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
```

**3. or with** `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Hide ActionBar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Comment: still i had a faded actionbar, it is weird only in 6.0.1 devices i have this problem

Comment: Could you try this getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

Comment: @hadiaryahadiarya I've updated the answer could you check it now?

Answer (score 0):

create a new style xml and change it as the below

Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

it may work...